# Перенос отфильтрованных строк файлы в другой файл другой папки

Tags: bash

Задача: Допишите все строки файла `folder/ file2`, содержащие подстроку `host`, в конец файла `folder/test/ file1`. Выведите содержимое файла `file1` в коротком формате.

Понятные мне действия:

```
~/folder$ grep host file2 # получаю список который нужно дописать в конец >> другого файла во вложенной папке test/
```

пробовал:

```
~/folder$ grep host file2 | cat >> file1
~/folder$ grep host file2 | cat >> /folder/test file1
```

Comment: Не понятно что подразумевается под коротким форматом. Посмотрите программу `tee`, выводит данные на печать в терминал и записывает в файл

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```
~$ grep host ./folder/file2 >> ./folder/test/file1
```

Comment: А по данному пункту **Выведите содержимое файла file1 в коротком формате.** какой ответ?

Comment: Я не нашел инф. про "короткий формат", вывел как есть, если тот кто принимает задание прокомментирует этот момент, напишу.